# JS async/await: catch in caller instead of try/catch?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Async/await has definitely made my code cleaner and more DRY. I'm unsure about best practices when it comes to error handling. Most examples I've found have a `try`/`catch` in the `async` function. Do you have to have that if the caller has a `.catch()`? What is the advantage of Example2 over Example1 below?

Example1 ***without*** try/catch in the async function:

```
function addReminder(data) {
  /*do some stuff*/
  saveReminder(data)
    .then(/*do some stuff*/
    .catch(error => console.log("Error saving reminder"));
}

async function saveReminder(data) {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('reminders', JSON.stringify(data));
  /* do some stuff */
}
```

Example2 ***with*** try/catch in the async function:

```
function addReminder(data) {
  /*do some stuff*/
  saveReminder(data)
    .then(/*do some stuff*/)
    .catch(error => console.log("Error saving reminder"));
}

async function saveReminder(data) {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('reminders', JSON.stringify(data));
    /* do some stuff */
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To catch exception from async function, the call need to be awaited. So, if you are not awaiting it, you have only option as in Example 1. However, if it is awaited, if you can use either option.

In example 2, you have additional benefit that if you get exact location where error occurred, it can useful to log it before throwing the error. The catch at end of promise as in your code after function `saveReminder` will catch any unhandled exception, no more matter which promise chain it occurred.